# Un-markdown text?

Tags: php, html, markdown

So I'm using Markdown to format text input from user:

http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

But I'm doing this destructively, so the text turns into HTML before database update. Can I transform it back to markdown when displaying it on the screen? The reason is that I want to allow the user to edit that text, and need it in the original form...

Comment: Not easily, but your could with some margin of error.  My question is, why are you storing HTML in the database when it takes up more space?

Comment: I would actually nowadays store it twice. Keep the markdown for editing and the readily converted html for display. (But of course, a separate cache would work as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/ ?

However, I should note that you should generally not store display formats in your database. It's worth considering storing the markdown in the DB and converting it to HTML on demand.

Comment: This is bad advice. You should store ***both*** in the database. That way you preserve the original for loading in an editor, and you don't waste processing time converting your original on every pageload.

Comment: @AndrewHeath I disagree. You may want to **cache** the converted form, but that's better done in something like memcache than in your permanently-persisted database. You can make the argument that "storage is cheaper than time", but enlarging the database is actually costing you both - a larger DB means a higher average access latency. It's also a DRY violation: if the database stores two copies of the same information, those two copies must be kept in sync. Furthermore, optimizing performance at the expense of clean design should only happen after you know you need the speed.

Comment: @AndrewHeath Actually, it's possible that storing the converted form in your database would be *slower* than doing the conversion on demand. This is likely to be the case if the site in question has a fast processor but a slow hard drive - the markdown is more concise than the HTML it represents, and having a database more than 2x the size means less of it will fit in RAM. Before running benchmarks, it's very unwise to make a decision like this - premature optimization is the devil.

Comment: I respect your position, but you're the only person I've seen advocate it so far on SO. Other related questions always propose the dual-storage approach to markdown and HTML. It seems hard to imagine a scenario where hard drive speed becomes a problem when delivering HTML unless we're considering Alexa-level traffic. I think the simplicity and speed of select & print is a better method here. But comments are for discussions like this, so the asker can make a more informed decision.

Comment: @AndrewHeath I don't believe I'm the first person to support this position. If you store both the markdown and the HTML, your database schema cannot be 3NF. Normalizing a database table is super common and there are dozens of questions about it. The reason I brought up the performance was to counter your "wasting processing time" comment - **never** say "this will be better because it's faster" until you've determined there is a need and run benchmarks. Optimization and pessimization are two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 2):

You should have two columns in your database: the original input (markdown syntax) and your post-markdown HTML.

When the page is loaded you pull the HTML.

If the user wants to edit you pull the markdown syntax original, and upon edit completion overwrite the HTML stored in the database.